# Why is my return empty (Node.js, unirest)

Tags: node.js, unirest

I have a problem with my little Node.js test setup. I basically want an endpoint that I can call, and this endpoint can call different other endpoints and give me a JSON as a response. When I have a look at the console output of the performRequest function, everything looks good. But the return of this function doesn't get passed. I always get an empty {} as a response.

The routes.js that holds my routes:

```
var s24 = require("./s24");

var routes = function(app) {

  app.get("/ping", function(req, res) {
    res.send("<p>pong</p>");
    console.log("Received GET");
  });

  app.get("/getCategories", function(req, res) {
    var output = s24.getCategories();
    res.type('application/json');
    return res.send(output);
  });

};

module.exports = routes;
```

The s24.js that queries another REST-API:

```
var functions = require('./functions');

var appID = "XYZ";
var authorization = "ABC";

var getCategories = function () {
  var output = functions.performRequest("https://api.s24.com/v3/"+appID+"/categories", authorization);
  console.log(output);
  return output;
};

module.exports.getCategories = getCategories;
```

The functions.js that holds all my relevant functions:

```
var unirest = require('unirest');

var performRequest = function(endpoint,authorization,body) {
  unirest.get(endpoint)
  .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': authorization})
  .send(body)
  .end(function (response) {
  var data = response.body;
  console.log(data);
  return data;
  });
};

module.exports.performRequest = performRequest;
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Can you show me how I can accomplish this within my code? What part do I need to change?

Comment: the function performRequest should return a promise, and then use `performRequest.then(response => console.log(response))`

Answer (score 0):

`performRequest` is an asynchronous function usually in node.js you can't just return the response of an asynchronous function. You can use `async await` feature with babel but the simplest way is just to use `callbacks` or `promises`.
Your code should look something as following:

```
var performRequest = function (endpoint, authorization, body, callback) {
  unirest.get(endpoint)
    .headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': authorization
    })
    .send(body)
    .end(function (err, response) {
      var data = response.body;
      callback(data["id"]);
    });
}


var getCategories = function () {
  var output = functions.performRequest(
    "https://api.s24.com/v3/" + appID + "/categories",
    authorization,
    function (output) {
      console.log(output);
    });
};
```

As you can see passing the response from one callback to an other is seems ugly so I suggest you to rethink your design.